# How to install GrumPHP with Composer 2?

Tags: composer-php

I updated my Composer to use version 2, but since then my Composer install doesn't work anymore.

[image: GrumPHP Composer 2]

```
The "phpro/grumphp" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("~1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - phpro/grumphp is locked to version v0.14.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpro/grumphp v0.14.3 requires composer-plugin-api ~1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: v0.14.3 of that package is nearly three years old. Why not update it to any more recent version? Any version released in the last year should not cause that error

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep it running, you will need to switch your [GrumPHP](https://github.com/phpro/grumphp) package to the version without dependencies.

```
composer remove phpro/grumphp
composer require --dev phpro/grumphp-shim
```